# Changes in my child theme from customizer not appearing in style.css?

Tags: customization, child-theme

I have made some changes (colours, etc...) in the appearance customize from my child theme, is actually working as is just applying to my child, but when I open the style.css from my child I don't see any change, where these changes are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the WordPress Customizer: These changes are not saved to the style.css, but they come most likely to be found shortly before `</head>`. Probably you will find there something like

```
<style>
//definitions via Customizer
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, but on which file are the changes saved?

Comment: I have just three files in my child, rtl.css functions.php and style.css, and changes made in the appearance are just applied for my child, as when I activate the parent, I can see the changes are not there, which is correct for me...

Comment: they are saved in the database and get injected via php. no files get changed here.

Comment: understand, thanks, so there is a db specific for the child? so the style.css file is just used to make changes manually? thanks in advance (I am new in wordpress :) )

Comment: i see. no. basically the style.css is getting displayed. if you change settings in the WordPress Customizer (https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API), these changes are stored in the DB and outputted inline after the style.css. By this, they overwrite the style.css settings.

Comment: in this case is it the correct way to make changes in the appearance or should be done manually in the css?

Answer (score 0):

The theme changes in customizer are applied `inline` or before the `</head>` to your WordPress site.

Technically speaking there are three hooks: `$wp_customize` `customize_register` `wp_head` which are used by theme developers to include the changes directly to theme without using the default style.css